# Spacing problem with microtype and Hoefler Text under xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, microtype, hoefler

I'm seeing an odd spacing problem with microtype and Hoefler Text under XeLaTeX. A minimal example is provided below. When typeset with xelatex, the word "he" and the emphasized word "ought" overlap as shown here:

[image: image depicting spacing problem]

The problem disappears if I use a different font (e.g., Palatino), or drop the microtype package, or even drop the first sentence. Any insights as to what's causing this problem greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}

For some cause, which I could not at the moment divine,
Arthur was unusually grave and silent during our walk home.
It could not be connected with Eric Lindon, I thought, as he
had for some days been away in London: so that, having Lady
Muriel almost ‘all to himself’—for \emph{I} was only too
glad to hear those two conversing, to have any wish to
intrude any remarks of my own—he \emph{ought},
theoretically, to have been specially radiant and contented
with life.

\end{document}
```

Update for reference: I'm using current versions of TeX Live 2013, microtype (2.5a) and XeLaTeX (0.9999.3) as described in the questions below.

Comment: Does it occur if you use `he~\emph{ought},` ?

Comment: I had to use `\setmainfont[ItalicFont=HoeflerTextItalic.ttf]{HoeflerText.ttf}` because the font is only installed on my system for use with pdfLaTeX (not system-wide). However, the example then compiles fine without the issue shown in the image you posted. Perhaps it is a bug in the version of the font you have? Or perhaps your TeX installation is not current?

Comment: It doesn't happen with my `Hoefler Text.ttc` in the system fonts (version 8.0d2e1).

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me too.  Since the problem goes away if you take out `microtype`, then perhaps you have some broken local microtype settings for Hoefler.

Comment: @bombcar: Unfortunately, the problem still occurs with `he~\emph{ought}`.

Comment: @cfr: I'm using what seems to be the current version of XeLaTex (0.9999.3-2013052719), and (TeX Live 2013). The microtype version (2.5a) also seems to be current.

Comment: @Thruston: I'm guessing you're right that there's something wrong with the Hoefler Text installation, but I have no clue where microtype looks for its information. I haven't (knowingly) modified anything about the font. Maybe a microtype guru can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: @egreg: It looks like I'm using the same version of Hoefler Text (8.0d2e1).

Comment: @user48586 My version of XeTeX is “XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013061817 (TeX Live 2013)”

Comment: Mine is "XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013052719 (TeX Live 2013)". I find it doubtful the difference in build could account for it but I'll check.

Comment: The log file that TeX produces will tell you if micro type is using any local config files.

Comment: @Thruston: Looks like the only config files being loaded are those that came with TeXlive. It's loading /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg, which is dated May 26, 2013. No mention of Hoefler Text in that configuration file.